# How do I get a placeholder of 0?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, form, formatting, number

I want my InfoPath form to have numbers formatted like "010" instead of "10" to then sync with SharePoint.  How can I get my form to show the zero placeholder instead of two digits?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to use a string to represent the number, and a formula like this: concat(substring("0", 1, 2 - string-length(field)), field)

The formula needs adjustment if you desire multiple leading zeroes.  For example,
concat(substring('00', 1, 3 - string-length(field)), field)
should work for 2.  And so on.